# How to replicate UILabels automatic preferredMaxLayoutWidth

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

Is there a way in auto layout to replicate the effect of setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to automatic in my own `UIView` subclass?

Times and again I run into cases where I have a view that does has an intrinsic height which depends on its width, quite similar to an `UILabel` with `numberOfLines = 0`.

An example of this could be a view that contains a label, or a legend view that wraps items to a new line when needed (like a collection view).

In `intrinsicContentSize` you're not allowed to access the current frame, so having an external property like `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is necessary. But setting this manually is tedious and error prone, and with UILabel it's not necessary (anymore; since iOS 8 IIRC?).

Can I do this in a custom `UIView` subclass, so that the value of this property is inferred automatically (e.g. by inspecting constraints or something like this)?

Comment: `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` tells auto-layout how you want multiline text to wrap. Not sure how that would apply to a `UIView` (or other UI element) that does not have wrapping text? Maybe try to describe a specific example of how you would see that implemented?

Comment: A table with labels in it would be an example, or a legend. I'll update the question.

Comment: OK - I think I see what you're getting at... Interesting question - worth some thought...